# Eclipse remote debug spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I want to do a remote debug of an application which is submitted to Spark using the Command Prompt in Windows.

How could I provide Spark the remote debug port to start.

Comment: you want to debug means ? Do you want to check flow step by step right?

Comment: I want to do a remote DEBUG with eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can always do the `Remote Debugging` using `Spark` with `Java/scala`. If you want to check with small `dataset` with `localmode` then you can use the step debugger. Have a look on the `Java Debugger` and how it works first.

[Java step debugger](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm)

if you want to use the `Spark` specific **Debugging** in `Remotemode` Then check this link it has very nice example with step by step process.

[spark-remote-debugging](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/15030/spark-remote-debugging.html)

For debugging the driver you can add the following to your `spark-submit` command. Then set your remote debugger to connect to the node you launched your driver program on.

```
--driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

You can customize the `port` according to your need.
In this case, start your debugger in listening mode, then start your spark program and wait for the executor to attach to your debugger. It's important to set the number of executors to 1 or **multiple executors** will all try to connect to your `debugger`, likely causing problems. check the above example for more details.

If you are using [jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) then you can use this example [Spark remote debugging](http://danosipov.com/?p=779)

Comment: Thanks Indrajit,**--driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,addr ess=5005** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. export options,  address below is the port to listen from IDE (Intellij or Eclipse)

export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8086

2. Run spark application

   spark-submit --class prueba.SampleRDDTest pruebaTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

   **Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8086**
3. In IDE listen the machine where run the spark application, (i used a docker machine)

   Arguments to JVM: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8086
   host: 192.168.99.100 port: 8086